# Find the cubic Maclaurin polynomial for $\sinh x$ and estimate the remainder on the interval $|x| \le 1 $

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm working through the above problem, and am having trouble deciphering what it means by "estimate the remainder on the interval $|x| \le 1$".

I found the Maclaurin polynomial to be $$P_3(x) = x + \frac{x^3}{6}$$

And I found the error term to be $$R_3(x) = \frac{\sinh(c)x^4}{24}, -1 \le c \le 1$$

But I don't know how to go any further. How am I supposed to estimate the error over the interval given, do I just use the largest value of $c$?

EDIT:

the answer in my text book was given as:

$|R_3(x)| \lt \frac{\sinh 1}{24} \lt \frac{1}{16}$

Comment: Use the largest conceivable value of $\sinh c$.  The upper bound given in the text is correct, but one can do better.

Comment: @AndréNicolas where did the value $1/16$ come from in their answer?

Comment: No idea. Indeed $\frac{\sinh 1}{24}\lt \frac{1}{16}$ but it is not a good approximation. And in fact the error is less than $\frac{\cosh 1}{120}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How did you calculate that error? By computer or by hand? If by hand, please outline your steps so I can learn

Comment: The Lagrange form of the remainder, since we are in that "chapter." But if we are truncating just after the $x^3$ term, and the $x^4$ term is $0$, the error is equal to $R_4(x)$. Another way to do it is that the error is $x^5/5!+x^7/7!+x^9/9!+\cdots$. This has absolute value less than the geometric series $|x|^5/5!\left(1+|x|^2/(6)(7)+|x|^4/((6)(7))^2+\cdots\right)$, whose sum is easily found.